# Arithmetic operator precedence quirk

Tags: objective-c, arithmetic-expressions

In C, since the addition operator (+) takes precedence before subtraction (-), I assume the following expression will return `0`:

`5 - 1 + 4`

But no, it return `8` instead. Why is that?

P.S.: The expression was tested in Objective-C.

**EDIT**: Apparently my assumption about addition taking precedence over subtraction is wrong. Please feel free to close this post if it is deemed as not helpful.

Comment: FWIW, I'm not aware of any number system where addition has precedence over subtraction.

Comment: See [Operators in C and C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence). Ignore the C++ ones and the rest apply to Objective-C since it is a superset of C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because addition *doesn't* take precedence over subtraction. Both have the same precedence, and are associated left to right., so `5 - 1 + 4` is equivalent to `(5 - 1) + 4`.

(The order of evaluation is unspecified, which matters only if the operands have side effects.)